# how to get only last line

Tags: python, dataframe

columns= ['LotFrontage', 'Alley', 'MasVnrType', 'MasVnrArea', 'BsmtQual',   'BsmtCond',     'BsmtExposure',     'BsmtFinType1',     'BsmtFinType2',
'Electrical',     'FireplaceQu',     'GarageType',     'GarageYrBlt',
'GarageFinish',     'GarageQual',     'GarageCond',     'PoolQC',
'Fence',
'MiscFeature']

```
list=[]
for i in columns:
    a=df_train[i].isnull().sum()
    list.append(a)
    print(list)
```

result:

```
[259]
[259, 1369]
[259, 1369, 8]
[259, 1369, 8, 8]
[259, 1369, 8, 8, 37]
[259, 1369, 8, 8, 37, 37]
[259, 1369, 8, 8, 37, 37, 38]
[259, 1369, 8, 8, 37, 37, 38, 37]
[259, 1369, 8, 8, 37, 37, 38, 37, 38]
[259, 1369, 8, 8, 37, 37, 38, 37, 38, 1]
[259, 1369, 8, 8, 37, 37, 38, 37, 38, 1, 690]
[259, 1369, 8, 8, 37, 37, 38, 37, 38, 1, 690, 81]
[259, 1369, 8, 8, 37, 37, 38, 37, 38, 1, 690, 81, 81]
[259, 1369, 8, 8, 37, 37, 38, 37, 38, 1, 690, 81, 81, 81]
[259, 1369, 8, 8, 37, 37, 38, 37, 38, 1, 690, 81, 81, 81, 81]
[259, 1369, 8, 8, 37, 37, 38, 37, 38, 1, 690, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81]
[259, 1369, 8, 8, 37, 37, 38, 37, 38, 1, 690, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 1453]
[259, 1369, 8, 8, 37, 37, 38, 37, 38, 1, 690, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 1453, 1179]
[259, 1369, 8, 8, 37, 37, 38, 37, 38, 1, 690, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 1453, 1179, 1406]
```

Am getting result as shown above, but i need only one list as

```
[259, 1369, 8, 8, 37, 37, 38, 37, 38, 1, 690, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 1453, 1179, 1406]
```

Comment: Unindent `print(list)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list=[]
for i in columns:
    a=df_train[i].isnull().sum()
    list.append(a)
print(list)
```

Comment: can help to find dtype of function using if statement to write loop for i in col:
    if df_train[i]=='int':
        print("True")

Comment: with this loop i have to fill na values by knowing dtype

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `print` out of the `for` loop, and it will print the last line only